# dial tcp: lookup XXXX on XXXX:53: dial udp XXXX:53: socket: operation not permitted

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I have a strange problem.

when I try to connect mysql storage,the phenomenon occured!

```
dial tcp: lookup XXXX on XXXX:53: dial udp XXXX:53: socket: operation not permitted
```

I cannot find out the question

Comment: Please share more info with us. Port 53/UDP is used for DNS queries, is your XXXX server running both DNS and MySQL servers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.